# VDI needs to reboot after session

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vdi

I'm trying to build a VDI solution for a small number (< 5) of clients.  The user will RDP to a VM and browse the web.  When they logout, I want the VM to revert back to a known state (snapshot).  How do I configure the VM to do this? We have vSphere 6.

Comment: Would it be an option to have the VM reboot on each logout?

Comment: Yes, but it has to reboot with no information or state saved from a previous session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of buying VMware Horizon (which is *sort* of mean for this exact situation...), you can kind of achieve what you're looking for using a combination of straight vSphere and Windows GPOs.

You'd have to:

1. Change the VM's disks to 'Nonpersistent Independent' mode
2. Setup a Group Policy to remove all but the "Shutdown" option in the Start Menu
3. Setup a vSphere alarm, triggered by 'VM State = Powered Off' to turn it back on

Answer (score 0):

To have VMWare revert a VM to a snapshot after rebooting choose `VM` > `Settings` > `Options` > `Snapshots` and select `After powering off` and `Revert to snapshot`. (see [here](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_special_restrict_snapshot.html))

You could use group policy to disable the logout button and only allow them to restart the machine, or schedule a reboot task on the logout event.

Comment: That might work on workstation, but will it also work in Vsphere on a server?

Comment: I don't see why VMWare would think a "workstation" is any different from a "server".  It's going to revert the VM to the last snapshot no matter what the VM actually is.

Comment: I think what ron is talking about is that your solution seems only to be possible in the VMWare Workstation, not in VMware vSphere. I am using vSphere 5.5, and i cannot find an option like this.

Comment: Ah.  My bad, I misunderstood.